# Django - list of choice in a ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I want to customize a modelForm with a list of choices from 0 to 10.
I tried to add a widget, but can't figure out how to make it work :

```
class Abonnements(models.Model):
    id                          = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre_d_exemplaire         = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    numero_d_adherent           = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_d_enregistrement       = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)  # This field type is a guess.
    premier_numero_a_servir     = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    remarques                   = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    destinataire_facture        = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    adresse_facture             = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    code_postal_facture         = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    ville_facture               = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    personne                    = models.ForeignKey('personnes.Personnes',on_delete=models.PROTECT,)

    class Meta:
        db_table                = 'abonnements'
        ordering                = ['-date_d_enregistrement']


class  AbonnementsForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model   = Abonnements
        fields  = [ "nombre_d_exemplaire"    ]
        widgets = {'"nombre_d_exemplaire"    : forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=range(10))  }
```

Gives me an error :

```
'ChoiceField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'
```

Comment: Show your full code.

Comment: Show us your `Abonnements` model, what is the field `nombre_d_exemplaire`? You can't assign a `ChoiceField` as the widget... You can however say: `widgets = {'nombre_d_exemplaire': forms.RadioSelect(choices=range(10))}`

Comment: I edited the code.

Comment: maybe will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679181/django-error-choicefield-object-has-no-attribute-is-hidden

Answer (score 2):

I think that the [`choices` parameter expects a List of Tuples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices). It should be something like:

```
forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=[(x, x) for x in range(10)])
```

Because we need to pass a "value" and a "key" format, the first one is used as value on the inputs and the second one as a Label for that value. You also can use something like:

```
[('first', 'First'), ('second', 'Second'), ('third', 'Third')]
```

Comment: I think i know whats happening, you are using a FormField inside the Widgets attribute, try this: `widgets = {"nombre_d_exemplaire": forms.RadioSelect( choices=range(10))}`, if you want to use a ModelField, you need to defined it inside the Model instead of the `Meta:` config.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, 
you can do as follows:
 first create a list before the class definition:

```
 options = []
 for i in range(0,11):
     options.append((i,i))
```

then add the needed field explicitly:

```
 number = forms.ChoiceField(choices=options)
```